# Magento - Add own phtml with getChildHtml

Tags: magento

In 1column.phtml i added the follow line:

```
<div id="ja-container" class="ja-lo-1col wrap">

     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('storeinfo.pthml'); ?>
```

I added the storeinfo.phtml file to the page/html folder. I know i have to add something to an xml file, but i have no idea what. Does someone knows what i have to do, to make it work?

storeinfo.phtml contains:

```
<div class="storeinfo">
<p class="StoreName"><?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?></p>
<br/>
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_description'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first make an entry in your layout XML as given below:

```
<block type="module/file" name="myblock" as="myblock" template="PATH_TO_storeinfo.phtml"/>
```

and then you can use following line in your phtml file where you want that phtml to be included:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('myblock'); ?>
```

where myblock is the name and alias for your block defined in the layout XML.

Comment: Does it care where i put it in the xml file?

Comment: Not really...but make sure it is under the same controller tag where you want it to make visible

Comment: I added your code above the breadcrumbs at the xml file, but still nothing.

Comment: Did you replace the proper value for the attributes like type, template etc. If yes, can you share what did you add in layout xml and under which section...I am assuming that you added that entry in relevant controller under "content" block

Comment: I thought it was something like this:

    <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
    </block>
            
    <block type="page/html_storeinfo" name="myblock" as="myblock" template="page/html/storeinfo.phtml"/>
            
    <block type="core/text_list" name="content-mass-top" as="content-mass-top" translate="label">
                <label>Content Mass Top</label>
    </block>

Answer (score 0):

The getChildHtml() function fetches the child block in a parent block.
For example:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
      <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
</block>
```

The code above is the layout for ‘catalog/product/view.phtml’, here you can use

```
$this->getChildHtml('media')
```

to fetch the media block and output it in the place where the function is called. The child block which you need to output in the parent file should have an argument named ‘as’, which you would use in the getChildHtml() function.

Answer (score 0):

you can addd below code to your local.xml or any module layout xml

```
<default>
     <reference name="footer">
         <block type="core/template" name="storeinfo" template="storeinfo.phtml"/>
     </reference>
</default>
```

please check your template path as well.

hope this will help you.

Comment: I added your code to the page.xml file, but nothing happened... did i do something wrong? I changed the path to: page/html/storeinfo.phtml

Comment: did you added my above code at right place ? it should work. or follow this http://aaronbonner.io/post/606455710/creating-a-custom-template-block-in-magento